# Android orientation change (onConfigurationChanged / OrientationEventListener)

Tags: android

I'm new to Android\Java and I have following question:
How can I check for screen orientation change?

Of course I have found many articles about this topic, however none of them worked for me so probably I'm doing something wrong.

One thing I don't understand is:
Do I need to implement an OrientationEventListener ? 
Or is "onConfigurationChanged" sufficient ? 
Or do I need both ?

For example I've tried to run the folloing code that uses "onConfigurationChanged" - but onConfigurationChanged is never called.
(I've add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" to manifest.xml and I build for API >13)

So my question is:
Why is "onConfigurationChanged()" never executed ?
I've tried it on a real device (Samsung Galaxy Note) and emulator.

```
public class main_activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)     <--- this is never called
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen     
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test.andro" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".main_activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.andro"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: Ensure that you are not calling setRequestedOrientation() anywhere. This will cause onConfigurationChange() to not fire.

Comment: use layoutDirection like this   .android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale|layoutDirection" and set minSdk with API 17 at least .

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    orientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            if(canShow(orientation)){
                show();
            } else if(canDismiss(orientation)){
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    orientationListener.enable();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    orientationListener.disable();
}

private boolean isLandscape(int orientation){
        return orientation >= (90 - THRESHOLD) && orientation <= (90 + THRESHOLD);
    }

private boolean isPortrait(int orientation){
    return (orientation >= (360 - THRESHOLD) && orientation <= 360) || (orientation >= 0 && orientation <= THRESHOLD);
}

public boolean canShow(int orientation){
    return !visible && isLandscape(orientation);
}

public boolean canDismiss(int orientation){
    return visible && !dismissing && isPortrait(orientation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code where you want to check orientation in your activity:

```
protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  super.onResume();

  int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        // DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        // getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        if(rotation == 0)
            text="Portrait";
        else if(rotation == 1)
            text="Rotated left side";
        else
            text="Rotated right side";

  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
        toast.show();
}
```

Comment: your theory is so bad :) please read again your solution ... only call 1 time ... your need a listener ..

Comment: You are right but we can write this code in onResume(), then it will work fine. i am editing my answer

Comment: Yes, you can put : (I don't know if is a bug 16/12/2015) android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"  "+" onConfigurationChanged (Awesome) you can get full control from XML and Java, Note (normally can't use android:configChanges with  onConfigurationChanged ) I'm using 2 methods and works correctly